# Unsure why my many to many lookup table is throwing a FK reference error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

For the sake of brevity I will trim everything down a bit. I have two models that will have a many to many relationship. The Models are Users and Domains. Domains in this context is a certain area of a large company, like a parent company, its sister company, and maybe some small companies that are all under the same umbrella. This is the User.cs Model

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Domains = new HashSet<Domain>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Domain.cs model:

```
public class Domain
{
    public Domain()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DomainId { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then I do this fancy magic in my Context.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Domains)
            .WithMany(p => p.Users)
            .Map(
            m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("DomainId");
                m.MapRightKey("UserId");
                m.ToTable("DomainUsers");
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

This creates the DomainUsers table just fine. Makes the two column table with DomainID and UserID.

In my seeded data I have one users (UserId = 1), and three domains (IDs= 1,2,3). On the lookup table I can add one record:

```
UserID | DomainId
1      |  1
```

But if I try to add the another one:

```
UserID | DomainId
1      |  1
1      |  2
```

I get the following error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_dbo.DomainUsers_dbo.Users_DomainId". Conflict occured in database "MyDatabase"
table "dbo.Users", column "UserId"
```

Am I missing some fundamental database design concept here, or is there something else to do with entity framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is backwards. From an [MSDN Blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx)

```
> modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
>                 .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
>                 .WithMany(t => t.Posts)
>                 .Map(mc =>
>                    {
>                        mc.ToTable("PostJoinTag");
>                        mc.MapLeftKey("PostId");
>                        mc.MapRightKey("TagId");
>                    });
```

> You’ll need to take care when specifying which is MapLeftKey and
>   which is MapRightKey. Left will be the key of the first class you
>   pointed to, which is Post, and right is for the other side of the
>   relationship. If you get these backwards, your data will be stored
>   incorrectly and your users will be very confused.

Try:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Domains)
            .WithMany(p => p.Users)
            .Map(
            m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("DomainId");
                m.ToTable("DomainUsers");
            });
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Mark! So to clarify, the left key needs to be whatever key is in modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>(), right?

Comment: Great, should be easy enough to remember. Thanks again!